# How to format sum into currency

Tags: php, mysql

Having a lot of problems, I am using SUM on a field in my table and it works but only with one decimal place, I need it to be in currency format, I have tried the below code and others but nothing

```
$query = "SELECT purchase concat('$', sum(purchase), 2) from dtable"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total ". $row['SUM(purchase)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `money_format` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 1):

First off, please don't use the `mysql*` functions as they are deprecated. Move to the `mysqli*` functions.  [See the PHP Docs for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

How about this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('$', ROUND(SUM(`purchase`), 2)) AS `result` 
FROM `dtable`
```

`CONCAT` just concatenates fields together so, in your case, you would end up with `$###2`.  You need a function (like `ROUND`) to format the number as you want.  `ROUND` take the number of desired decimal places as the first argument.  More on `ROUND` (and other MySQL math functions) here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

You could also do this all in PHP using [number_format](http://php.net/number_format).

Change

```
$query = "SELECT purchase concat('$', sum(purchase), 2) from dtable";
....     
echo "Total ". $row['SUM(purchase)'];
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(`purchase`) AS `sumOfPurchase` FROM `dtable`"; 
....
echo 'Total $' . number_format($row['sumOfPurchase'], 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',FORMAT(sum(purchase),2)) as purchase from dtable
```

will give results like $1,234,567.89